# How to incorporate boundary conditions into this nonhomogenous ODE?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

I have ODE given by $\mu X\frac{du}{dX} + 1/2\sigma^{2}X^{2}\frac{d^2u}{dX^2} = -2$

and I am given that $u(X_{0})=0$ and $u(X_{1})=0$

I have calculated a complementary solution with real roots, can you give me any hints how I should proceed to obtain solution with incorporated conditions?

Answer (score 0):

Hint.

Considering that

$$
a x u' + b x^2 u''=-2
$$

is a linear ODE we have

$$
u = \frac{x^{1-\frac ab}}{1-\frac ab}c_1 + c_2- \frac{\ln((a-b)x)}{a-b}
$$

then with the boundary conditions

$$
\cases{
\frac{x_1^{1-\frac ab}}{1-\frac ab}c_1 + c_2- \frac{\ln((a-b)x_1)}{a-b} = 0\\
\frac{x_2^{1-\frac ab}}{1-\frac ab}c_1 + c_2- \frac{\ln((a-b)x_2)}{a-b} = 0
}
$$

we determine $c_1, c_2$

NOTE

Due to linearity, as $v = v_h+v_p$, first we solve the homogeneous part

$$
a x v_h + b x^2 v_h'= 0\Rightarrow \frac{v'_h}{v_h}+ \frac{a}{bx} = 0\Rightarrow v_h = x^{-\frac ab}c_1
$$

with $v_h = u'_h$. The particular is obtained with variation of constants (Lagrange) and gives $v_p = \frac{2x^{-1}}{1-\frac ab}$ hence

$$
v = v_h + v_p = x^{-\frac ab}c_1+\frac{2x^{-1}}{1-\frac ab}
$$

etc.

Comment: Thank you. Can you explain how did you obtain u because I have three cases with real roots, complex roots and identical roots.

Comment: Integrating $v$ (in the NOTE) we obtain $u$

Comment: I see. It's not very clear from the note that how $v_{p}$ is obtained - can you shed more light on that? Because this is precisely my problem

Comment: We make $v_p = x^{-\frac ab}c_1(x)$ and after substitution on the complete ODE for $v$ we obtain $c_1'(x)$. After solving this integration, we finally have $c_1(x) = -\frac{2 x^{\frac{a}{b}-1}}{a-b}$

Comment: What is the method that is used to solve this for v? Because I am not sure whether I am familiar with it.

Comment: And one more question: why do you have $v_{h}=x^{-1/b}c_{1}$ - if we integrate shouldn't it be $e^{-a/xb}$?